# adding metadata info on a jenkins plugin xml that doesnt show up on UI?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly

IS there a way to add a metadata xml in your jenkins job plugin that doesnt show up UI but can be populated by going into config.xml ?

I have something like this :

```
<!--
@author Kuber Kaul
-->

<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:f="/lib/form" xmlns:r="/lib/pib" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler">
    <f:section title="${%xxx}">
        <f:dropdownList name="details" title="${%xxx}">
            <j:forEach var="s" items="${descriptor.artifactoryServers}" varStatus="loop">
                <f:dropdownListBlock value="${s.name}" title="${s.url}" selected="${s.name==instance.artifactoryName}">
                    <f:nested>
                        <input type="hidden" name="artifactoryName" value="${s.name}"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="artifactoryUrl" id="artifactoryUrlDeploy${s.url}" value="${s.url}"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="stapler-class" value="dj.pib.productivity.ServerDetails"/>

                        <f:entry 
                        title="${%Module Name}" name="module" readOnlyTextbox>
                        pam         
                        </f:entry>
```

but this read only text box doesn't seem to send "pam" in the backend but null. Any way around it ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't really understand your question.  What do you mean by "metadata XML"?
The Jelly setup you're describing *will* show up in the UI (as a read-only textbox).

If you want the value `pam` to be hardcoded in a job's configuration, there's no need to place that in your Jelly XML — just hardcode that value in the Java code, where it's required.

In any case, to fix your Jelly, the syntax of this part is not correct:

```xml
<f:entry title="${%Module Name}" name="module" readOnlyTextbox>
    pam
</f:entry>
```

[`readOnlyTextbox`](https://jenkins-ci.org/maven-site/jenkins-core/jelly-taglib-ref.html#form:readOnlyTextbox) is a tag, not an attribute on `entry`, so it should probably look like this:

```xml
<f:entry title="${%Module Name}" field="module">
    <f:readOnlyTextbox value="pam" />
</f:entry>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my question is that I create the jenkins job with my custom config.xml that has this plugin in there. But I want to supply(add that to the xml) some metadata value along with the the config.xml that I can read during job runs but I dont want to give ability to the user to change that value. So I am not sure this will do.

Comment: The problem with above is that I cannot populate the read only box with value during creating jenkins job in the config.xml as the value wont show up. Is there a way to : <f:readOnlyTextbox value="pam">jobName <f:readOnlyTextBox/> ..do something like this and recieve jobName in the backend ??

Comment: In conclusion - I want some xml tag that I can use in the backend and can be populated in config.xml during job creation but doesnt show up in the UI.

Comment: You could just disable job configuration editing on this job for the people that you don't trust?

Comment: If you are writing a plugin, what you've described should work — you just need to make sure your `module` field is saved, i.e. it's listed in your `@DataBoundConstructor` or in a `@DataBoundSetter`.